# Is there any software available for viewing .Pages Extension?

Tags: iwork

I'm using Windows and Mac for a few work projects and I want to view iWork files in Windows.

Is there any anything viewer or software available for viewing files with a `.pages` extension?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the Pages documents yourself, you can save it in MS Word format.

```
File -> Save As -> Save Copy As Word Document
```

If you are just trying to open a .pages file in Windows, you can try changing the file extension to .zip. And then try to access the contents of the Pages doc by unzipping the renamed file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Pages documents viewer available for Windows.

If you want to *view* the documents in Windows (as your question title states), you should make it a habit of exporting them to PDF.

For editing, @CaseyIT's answer is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs contains a viewer for Apple Pages' files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending o what you want to view a pages file is actually a zip file with the images and some XML giving the layout and text. If you unzip it you can view the images and text etc. although you won't be able to view the formatted document using this method.